# 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and attempting to compile code that has worked before I updated from VS 2013.

> 'inet_addr': Use inet_pton() or InetPton() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

in this code:

```
partner.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.c_str());
```

I attempted to use the functions mentioned but they were undefined. I attempted to define the macro in many different spots but nothing happened. Another thread said that I should include Ws2tcpip.h instead of WinSock2 & add Ws2_32.lib. I already have the library added, and when I used the include nothing happened. What is going on?!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The ip string can be converted to the [in_addr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms738571(v=vs.85).aspx) structure with the [InetPton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx) function.
It is used like this:

```
InetPton(AF_INET, strIP, &ipv4addr)
```

You need to include the "Ws2tcpip.h" header file, use the library "Ws2_32.lib" and DLL "Ws2_32.dll".

Answer (score 39):

Just to make the conversion clear. Let's say you have code using the deprecated [inet_addr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx) as in this example:

```
RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.1");
```

It could be converted to the newer [InetPton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx) as follows:

```
InetPton(AF_INET, _T("192.168.1.1"), &RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
```

The [_T](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) macro prevents the "*const char incompatible with PCWSTR*" error.

Comment: Alternative cast: (PCWSTR)("192.168.1.1") -  _T can be misleading, plus the shorthand didn't work for me, Note still requires headers.

Comment: Alternative alternative cast: InetPton(AF_INET, L"192.168.1.1", &RecvAddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

Answer (score 11):

You can try

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
```

for using `inet_addr()`.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you define  _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS before all the include.

Comment: There's a reason for that warning. Blankly recommending to set this define reinforces bad style and delays what the warning points to: the need for modernizing the code. The use of `inet_addr` for example causes thread-safety issues. Even locally disabling the deprecation warning would be a better option since it makes the issue visible.